# How to make functional component rerender properly on parents state chage?

Tags: reactjs

please help me figure out why the component works like that.
I have a functional component something like this:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  const { dataArr } = props;
  [ownDataArr, setOwnDataArr] = useState([...dataArr]);
  // doesn't change after changing in the state of the parent component
  console.log(ownDataArr);
  return (
    // ownDataArr is used here
  );
```

It receives `dataArr` from parent component via props (parent component contains this in state). And when changed in parent component after `MyComponent` rerenders, `ownDataArr` stays the same. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. The child component needs the state, since it must be able to change the received data without constantly sending it to the parent.

Comment: you have to update the state on props update.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    setOwnDataArr([...dataArr]);
  }, [dataArr]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to update the state on props change

```
useEffect(() => {
    setOwnDataArr(dataArr)
}, [dataArr])
```

This is because state initialize on the first render of component with the props and when the props change, we have to update the state using useEffect

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  const { dataArr } = props;
  [ownDataArr, setOwnDataArr] = useState([...dataArr]);
  
  // add useEffect wich depend on dataArr changing, 
  // because initial state is memoized by useState
  useEffect(() => setOwnDataArr(dataArr), [dataArr])
  return (
    // ownDataArr is used here
  );
}
```